# Squid radius authentication "No response from RADIUS server"

Tags: response, squid, radius

I have successfully configure freeradius with mysql.
i can radtest using command :

```
sudo radtest alice password 192.168.2.3 1812 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 187 to 192.168.2.3 port 1812
    User-Name = "alice"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 192.168.2.3 port 1812, id=187, length=20
```

Now i try squid using radius authentication.

i followed step by step from :

http://safesrv.net/setup-squid-and-freeradius-on-centos-5/#comment-1043

But i got error message log on cache.log

```
Warning: Received invalid reply digest from server
Warning: Received invalid reply digest from server
Warning: Received invalid reply digest from server
squid_rad_auth: No response from RADIUS server
```

On radius -X debug there is error message like bellow :

```
Sending duplicate reply to client localprivate port 42003 – ID: 2
Sending Access-Reject of id 2 to 192.168.2.3 port 42003
Waking up in 2.9 seconds.
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 192.168.2.3 port 42003, id=2, length=63
Sending duplicate reply to client localprivate port 42003 – ID: 2
Sending Access-Reject of id 2 to 192.168.2.3 port 42003
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Found Auth-Type = PAP
# Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group PAP {…}
[pap] login attempt with password “b9?I? +�(�Ч�Y�?”
[pap] Using clear text password “password”
[pap] Passwords don’t match
++[pap] returns reject
Failed to authenticate the user.
WARNING: Unprintable characters in the password. Double-check the shared secret on the server and the NAS!
Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
```

What is that error ? How i can solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Snoop your generated Accessreq and try to decode the encrypted password using your shared secret with wireshark. Looks like your test client doesnt encode the password correct.
Make sure testing123 is correctly configured on server side.